# JAVA Como hacer que un Sprite tenga comportamiento digonal?

Tags: java, poo, funciones, objeto

Estoy haciendo un juego y tengo el siguiente problema:
Cuando el jugador (una imagen) se mueve por afuera de la ventana en el eje X, hago que aparezca del lado contrario, y lo mismo cuando el jugador sale por el eje Y.

El problema es cuando lo hago salir en diagonal..
Cuando hago el movimiento en diagonal, el jugador aparece pero en otra parte del mapa y no siguiendo su respectiva hipotenusa. Adjunto una imagen y código por si sirve de ayuda:

```
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
// Si se va del eje X:
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39 && jugador.posicionX < anchoJuego) {
            jugador.setVelocidadX(5);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 37 && jugador.posicionX > -40) {
            jugador.setVelocidadX(-5);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 37) {
            jugador.setPosicionX(anchoJuego);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 39) {
            jugador.setPosicionX(-20);
        }
// Si se va del eje Y:
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 40 && jugador.posicionY < altoJuego) {
            jugador.setVelocidadY(5);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 38 && jugador.posicionY > -40) {
            jugador.setVelocidadY(-5);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 38) {
            jugador.setPosicionY(altoJuego);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == 40) {
            jugador.setPosicionY(-20);
        }
        

// Si se va del lado diagonal: 
             //...
        
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esta [respuesta de Loris Securo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551133/java-diagonal-movement)

Para obtener el desplazamiento diagonal, define un angulo diagonal, obten el coseno del angulo, lo sumas a la posiciòn en x y lo multiplicas por la velocidad, lo mismo para la posiciòn en y pero esta la sumas al seno del angulo y lo multiplicas por la velocidad.

Este es un ejemplo suponiendo un angulo de 30 grados

```
int x=0;
int y=0;
int speed = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){    
    double angle = 30.0;
    double angleInRadians = Math.toRadians(angle); //convierte grados a radianes.
    x += Math.cos(angleInRadians) * speed;  //movimiento horizontal.
    y += Math.sin(angleInRadians) * speed;  //movimiento vertical.
     System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " +y );    

 }
```

obtienes como salida las coordenadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las cuales pueden realizar el desplazamiento diagonal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]